# Linear Programming optimization Package for Python 3.3?

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.3, linear-programming

Is there any Linear programming optimization package available which will be compatible with Python 3.3 in windows 32-bits?
I have just tried CPLEX, PulP-or, and Pyomo, but I can not install them on Python 3.3!

I need to solve a LP problem for about 100 times, by changing some of its parameters each time I solve it.

I have already done this by LINGO 13 Optimization, but I don't like the LINGO syntax structure which is hard to implement.

Comment: Would you please replace LP with the long version so more people will read this question.

Comment: Have you found anything so far? Have you tried porting pulp yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/index.html) offers various linear optimization methods and [CVXOPT install](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html) describes Win32 installation steps.

Comment: [cvxpy](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy) wraps cvxopt, looks very nice, but is python 2.7 .

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) officially supports [python 3.2](http://www.gurobi.com/products/gurobi-optimizer/what%27s-new-in-v5.6#Additional).

Answer (score 0):

Scipy has an LP solver which runs on Python 3: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog